# Western Digital HDD disappears and reappears in BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, bios

I know many people asked about similar problems, but I have a very specific case where I can't understand what's going on...

I have a 3TB Western Digital Caviar Green disk connected in my Desktop, that also has a seagate 1.5TB disk and 2 SSD drives (OCZ and Sandisk).

After working fine for quite some time (probably more than a year), suddenly my Caviar Green drive disappeared from windows. I checked the BIOS, and it wasn't there either. I opened my PC, played with the connectors, power, etc, but nothing helped. Even tried switching connectors with those of the 1.5TB disk, and nothing changed, the 1.5TB seagate was there, but the 3TB WD was not.

Ok, now for the strange part. I have another desktop at home, so I took out my 3TB drive, connected it there, and it worked fine! I copied the most important files out of it, and then made another attempt in the original desktop. Surprise! It now appeared in the BIOS and worked fine! I even ran the SMART test with the WD tools and it said everything was intact.

It doesn't end here. After leaving it overnight in the original desktop, it disappeared again in the morning. I repeated the entire process, connecting it to the second desktop, and there it is again working fine.

Now for my question...

Whats going on? The disk seems to be appearing on/off in my original Desktop, while other drives there work fine. SMART test says the disk is fine.

Any ideas? Is the disk defective and should be replaced? Or maybe there's a problem with the controller in the desktop?

I'm using a Gigabyte GA-880GA-UD3H motherboard and tried connecting the drive to both bridges (SATA2 and SATA3 bridges).

Thanks

EDIT: Power options are set never to turn off hard drives:

[image]

Comment: Could be a power saving feature that disables power to the drive.  Check Power options in control panel and see if the hard drive is set to power down after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Power options haven't changed and it worked fine for a year. They're set to never turn off the Hard Drives.Except, it didn't appear in the BIOS when I rebooted, I don't think that can be caused by windows power saving configuration... Am I wrong?

Comment: No your not wrong.  Have you checked that you have the newest BIOS version for you motherboard?  Because the drive detected without any worries on another PC, with a different BIOS.  Be careful about updating the BIOS!!

Comment: I prefer not to update BIOS. But why would it stop detecting it after a year it worked fine? And why would it work again on the origonal pc after i connected to another pc?

Comment: If it was the onboard controller the other drives would do the same.  I can only think of an intermittent drive controller failure on the WD Green drive.

Comment: So you'd recommend to replace the drive, even though the SMART seems ok? Is this something the SMART would not be able to identify?

Comment: Harddrives can fail without SMART warnings.  If possible I would send it to someone that have the tools to check the controller. Check here:[link]http://www.howtogeek.com/134735/how-to-see-if-your-hard-drive-is-dying/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your disk is perfectly fine, do not replace it. The defect is clearly in the *connection* between the disk and your desktop. Somewhere in there, you have a defective contact, which worked for some time after you re-positioned the disk because you must have accidentally re-secured the contact, which then turned loose again as a consequence of the air blown by the cooling system, or some such thing.

It's the most economical hypothesis consistent with all the facts you presented. Find a USB disk enclosure, and test this hypothesis by checking whether the disk works on the same pc/same BIOS, but from the outside. My money is on it working.

Comment: I tried a different connector in the same PC (one that works fine for another disk), is that not enough to contradict this theory? Different connector includes different SATA port, different SATA cable and different power cable.

Comment: Halfway there, but not quite. Are the two SATA ports attache to the same portion of the bus or not? That's why I suggested a USB adapter, I was hoping to circumvent this "internal" ambiguity.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to get one. Any theory as to why only this one disk would be affected?

Comment: Yes, different part of the bus.

Comment: Works perfectly now... still not sure exactly what went wrong though. It works fine with all connectors now.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally discovered this solution. I now squarely placed my blame on Microsoft.

To recover your WD drive do the following:

1. Make sure your WD External Harddrive is switched on and connected to the PC or Laptop
2. Swipe with your mouse to the top right or press Windows + S
3. In the search windows, type Storage Spaces
4. Select the Storage Spaces and then click on Create New Storage Space
5. Windows will detect your WD drive and warn any files there will be lost. You will also notice your WD drive will now appear in the Windows Explorer
6. IF you want to keep your files, choose browse and you can select the files to copy to your PC
7. Now, create the storage space to have the permanent drive.